# Does Java creates a deep copy of the object or just link to its reference

Tags: java

Let say I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
aList.add(new String("abc");
...
String aString = aList.get(0);
```

Does aString have a deep copy of aList.get(0), which means a new memory location with the new String object, or aString is just assigned a reference pointer to the same object as aList has in position 0?

Comment: No. It would give you the same string as is what you stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit deep copy, the reference is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

`aString` holds a reference to the object created by the expression `new String("abc")`. It does not hold a reference to the first position of the list, so changing the list after the assignment does not change `aString`. Also, in Java, Strings are immutable objects, which means the value of the String itself cannot be changed.